# ORA-01036 after rewriting an Oracle insert command

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, sqldatasource

I am reworking legacy code and came to this query:

```
sqlDS.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE " +
                      "(ID, DATUM, ID_STATE, G_AM, G_VON, DATUM_BEW) " +
                      "VALUES     (" + ((strukturen.Login)Session["svar_bew"]).ID_Bew.ToString() +
                      ", TO_DATE('" + _datum + "', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 2, TO_DATE('" + lbl_bew.Text +
                      "', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'ID" + ((strukturen.Login)Session["svar_bew"]).ID_Bew.ToString() +
                      "', TO_DATE('" + _datum + "', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))";
```

Which works, but I want this abomination rewritten into a paramerterized format, for obious reasons.

Now this is my progress so far:

```
sqlDS.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE (ID, DATUM, ID_STATE, G_AM, G_VON, DATUM_BEW) " +
                      "VALUES (:Id_Bew, TO_DATE(':Datum', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 2, TO_DATE(':BewAm', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'ID' || :Id_Bew, TO_DATE(':Datum', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))";
                        sqlDS.InsertParameters.Add("Id_Bew", ((strukturen.Login)Session["svar_bew"]).ID_Bew.ToString());
                        sqlDS.InsertParameters.Add("Datum", _datum);
                        sqlDS.InsertParameters.Add("BewAm", lbl_bew.Text);
```

This is the table in question:

```
COLUMN      |    TYPE
-----------------------
ID          |    NUMBER
DATUM       |    DATE
/*  Columns |    ommited */
ID_STATE    |    NUMBER
G_AM        |    DATE
G_VON       |    CHAR(10 BYTE)
DATUM_BEW   |    DATE
```

The variables follow no fixed schema yet, so they were declared in German, never mind that in this case.
The problem is, that this new code now throws an ORA-01036 an I suspect that it is at this location:

`'ID" + ((strukturen.Login)Session["svar_bew"]).ID_Bew.ToString()` --> `'ID' || :Id_Bew`

In the original SQL query the string "ID" is concatinated with  an numeric ID which is pulled out of a session variable. My suspicion is, that I concatinated it the wrong way in my paramerterized query and botched up the syntax.

Question is: How can I resolve this error and bring this insert command into a proper format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind Variables Should be defined without embedding in single quotes.

`':bind_variable'` ---> Wrong (Treated as plain string instead)
  `:bind_variable`  ---> Right

So, When you attempted to add a bind parameter, it threw ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

```
 sqlDS.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE (ID, DATUM, ID_STATE, G_AM, G_VON, DATUM_BEW) " +
                          "VALUES (:Id_Bew, TO_DATE(:Datum, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 2, TO_DATE(:BewAm, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'ID' || :Id_Bew, TO_DATE(:Datum, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))";
                            sqlDS.InsertParameters.Add("Id_Bew", ((strukturen.Login)Session["svar_bew"]).ID_Bew.ToString());
                            sqlDS.InsertParameters.Add("Datum", _datum);
                            sqlDS.InsertParameters.Add("BewAm", lbl_bew.Text);
```